# How to pass data between controller-Service-controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind id from controller1 to one of myservice function.But I get below error

> TypeError: _this.dashboardService.chartid is not a function

Please find my code snippet

**Service1.js**

```
var Service1 = function (
        $http) {
        this.$http = $http;
};
Service1.prototype.chartid = function (id) {
        return id;
};

appmodule.service('dashboardService', DashboardService);
```

**controller1.js**

```
 Controller1.prototype.Chart = function (data) {
    _this.service1.chartid(data.key);
};
```

Comment: write a feedle, your code is nearly uncomprensible, and surely there is one error on the "__this" keyword, it's this not __this. Other than that we need to see you're controller and service declaration.

Comment: I write as var _this = this;

Comment: does the service work at all?  Is it just in this instance that you receive the error?

Comment: I am able to access remaining functions of service to other controller, but when i try to access above mentioned function, I get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't inject your service inside your controller, in more classic way:

```
var controller1=angular.module('controllermodule',[]);


controller1.controller('{name of the controller}',function({service to inject}){}
```

Comment: Thank you mautrok

Answer (score 0):

Javascript prototype functions can be invoked on its objects.When you add prototype you are defining the class whose functions are available on the object.

e.g.

```
var Service = function() {};

Service.prototype.callMePlease = function() {
   console.log('ok Calling now');
   return 'Just called';
};

console.log('callMePlease is undefined on Service or is it ? Service.callMePlease='+Service.callMePlease);

var serviceInstance = new Service();

console.log('callMePlease is NOT undefined on serviceInstance or is it ? serviceInstance .callMePlease='+serviceInstance.callMePlease);

var didYouCall = serviceInstance.callMePlease();

console.log('didYouCall='+didYouCall);
```

Given this you actually need the instance of service1 in your case.

It is best you follow Angular injection model as per [official angularjs DI documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to allow AngularJS create instances for you.

However you may use programattic approach (not advised). In your case

```
 Controller1.prototype.Chart = function (data) {
    var myService1 = $injector.get('service1');
    myService1.chartid(data.key);
};
```